flask db init using flask migrate
I was try to migrate my database using flask_migrate when i was hitting the flask db init that time
getting below error.
 Error: While importing 'app', an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Flask REST APIs\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 245, in locate_app    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Flask REST APIs\app.py", line 6, in <module>
    from db import db
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Flask REST APIs\db.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Flask REST APIs\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from flask import _app_ctx_stack, abort, current_app, request
ImportError: cannot import name '_app_ctx_stack' from 'flask' (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Flask REST APIs\.venv\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py)

Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'flask --help' for help.

Error: No such command 'db'.

I have try diffence version on flask to install and uninstall but it will geting same error or
diffence some things on it.

Looks like a (discouraged) import of a "private" object made by a lib does not work anymore. Make sure you are using recent version of the libs and flask.

You are using versions of Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy that are incompatible with each other. You may want to make sure that Flask, Flask-SQLAlchemy, SQLAlchemy, Flask-Migrate and Alembic are upgraded to their latest versions to eliminate incompatibilities between them.

Yes, it's correct when I have updated my requirement.txt then it will work :)
